# How to change export PDF font size in datatables?

Tags: pdf, datatables, font-size

I have a datatable and i have print button and pdf button.
I can change font size when print page but i can't change font size while exporting pdf file.

```js
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        text: 'Save PDF',
        exportOptions: {
            modifier: {
                page: 'current'
            }
        },
        header: true,
        title: 'My Table Title',
        orientation: 'landscape'
    }, 
    {
        extend: 'print',
        text: 'Print',
            customize: function ( win ) {
                $(win.document.body)
                    .css( 'font-size', '15pt' )


                $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
                    .addClass( 'compact' )
                    .css( 'font-size', '8pt' );
            },
            header: false,
            title: '',
            orientation: 'landscape'
     },
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you look at the src of [**html5.js**](http://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.1.0/js/buttons.html5.js), it creates a default object literal `doc` holding default settings :

```js
var doc = {
    pageSize: config.pageSize,
    pageOrientation: config.orientation,
    content: [
        {
            table: {
                headerRows: 1,
                body: rows
            },
            layout: 'noBorders'
        }
    ],
    styles: {
        tableHeader: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154',
            alignment: 'center'
        },
        tableBodyEven: {},
        tableBodyOdd: {
            fillColor: '#f3f3f3'
        },
        tableFooter: {
            bold: true,
            fontSize: 11,
            color: 'white',
            fillColor: '#2d4154'
        },
        title: {
            alignment: 'center',
            fontSize: 15
        },
        message: {}
    },
    defaultStyle: {
        fontSize: 10
    }
};
```

You can use the `customize` callback to change those default settings :

```js
{
   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   text: 'Save PDF',
   exportOptions: {
      modifier: {
         page: 'current'
      }
   },
   header: true,
   title: 'My Table Title',
   orientation: 'landscape',
   customize: function(doc) {
      doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 16; //<-- set fontsize to 16 instead of 10 
   }  
},
```

---

*Changing the header font size:*

```
doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 30
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/12/**

*Change alignment, set center to all headers, all columns all footers :*

```
doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'center'
```

**https://jsfiddle.net/2nwqa2jk/13/**

Comment: My table is left aligned in exported pdf. How do I align it in center?

Comment: I need to chane just header's font-size. I have changed body font-size

Comment: where i can see all the options?

Comment: @darioxlz, look at the pdfmake documentation, especially https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/document-definition-object/

Comment: How can I make the table occupy 100% of the width of the page in the PDF?

Comment: @darioxlz, use margins: [...], there are several answers here on SO about that (have answered myself, have no time to find them right now)