# How to move table export pdfhtml5 datatable?

Tags: jquery, pdf, datatables

I want to export datatable using pdfhtml
and this my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').DataTable( {
      dom: 'Bfrtip',
         buttons: [ {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            text: 'PDF with image'
         } ]
    } );
} );
```

and result export pdf like this

[image]
how to move the table to the center?
can I modify this layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `customize` callback to change the layout of the generated PDF. It is not so well documented (yet, I guess) but see the [PDFMake definition object docs](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) for insight of naming and object structures, and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33998231/1407478) (by me) as a very simple example of how to do.

AFAIK there is no option that let you force centering of the entire content (i.e a kind of `docDefinition.content.align` or similar) but you can overrule page margins and column widths.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [ {
       extend: 'pdfHtml5',
       text: 'PDF with image',
       customize: function(doc) {
          //pageMargins [left, top, right, bottom] 
          doc.pageMargins = [ 150, 20, 150, 20 ];
       }
    }]
});
```

This will effectively create a 150px left / right margin on each page, centering the table. Now you just have to figure out what margin size that suits your needs best. In that process you may need to force the width of the exported columns too :

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
       extend: 'pdfHtml5',
       text: 'PDF with image',
       customize: function(doc) {
          doc.content.forEach(function(item) {
             if (item.table) {
                // Set width for 3 columns
                item.table.widths = [100, 40, '*'] 
             } 
          });
       }
    }]
});
```

I am iterating over the `content` array since we cannot know for sure which index hold the `table` property. The above simply set a exported three column layout to have `100px`, `40px` and "the rest" widths. Use `'auto'` if you want the width to be adjusted to the content. Note, if your `item.table.widths` not exactly matches the numbers of columns in the table, the export will fail.

Anyway - by defining `pageMargin` and perhaps some minor adjusting of the widths of some of the columns, you should be able to create a centered PDF very easily.