# Data Table customising pdf

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery Data Table to export table as pdf.Now the pdf all the text are left aligned.How can I change it to right aligned?I need to add custom css to the exported pdf.

Here is my code

```
$('#reporTable').DataTable({

    "paging" : false,
    "ordering": false,
    "info" : false,
    "searching" : false,

    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
    "sSwfPath": "/javascripts/js/dataTables/tools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",

    "aButtons": [
    {
    "sExtends": "pdf",
    "sTitle": filename,
    "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
    "sPdfMessage": out_name+":" + msg
    },

    ],

    }

    });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the **`customize`** callback. It is not so well documented, see [this answer for some references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998231/how-to-change-export-pdf-font-size-in-datatables), or you could simply try to investigate the passed `doc` literal yourself. Basically

```js
customize: function(doc) {
  doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'right';
  doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'right';
}
```

will end up in a PDF with right aligned headers and cell content. A sample could be

```js
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
   extend: 'pdfHtml5',
   customize: function(doc) {
     doc.defaultStyle.alignment = 'right';
     doc.styles.tableHeader.alignment = 'right';
   }  
 }]
})
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/yzdtLz36/**

Comment: In the default doc layout is noBorders how can make it with borders?

Comment: @BibinJoseph, Sorry, I honestly dont know, never needed the feature. Tried a few things with no luck. I believe you have to iterate over each and every item in `doc.contents` and apply styles to each item.  dataTables only facilitates the basics from `pdfmake`, you could look at http://pdfmake.org for more exact info ...