# How to change export PDF typeface size in datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I want to change the typeface in the report datatable pdf
example, 
thank you very much for your help, this is what I have

```
buttons: [
        {

            extend: 'colvis',
            extend: 'pdfHtml5', 

            header: true,
            //title: 'sys',
            orientation: '',
            pageSize: 'letter',
            fontSize: '10',
            font: 'Courier new',

            exportOptions : {
              columns : [0,1,2,3,4,5,6], 
                stripHtml : false 
                },

            customize: function ( doc ) {

                 doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                     fillColor:'#525659',
                     color:'#FFF',
                     fontSize: '10',
                     alignment: 'left',
                     bold: true,    
                    // font:''

                  },  //para cambiar el
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*typeface size*"? Besides that, the code snippet above would never work. Take a look at https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/

Comment: hi friend, if the snippet of code works, and I mean font size

Comment: you can use `doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 20` and similar, see https://jsfiddle.net/drh82tsm/ and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34007650/1407478

Comment: I'm not looking to change the size of the font, something like font-family "vedana" "courier"

Comment: That explains why you are using the term "typeface" :) You need to make your own vsf_fonts.js, here is a recipe -> https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side Have never tried it myself.

Comment: thank you friend, I will try!!